# what is wrong with my my.cnf file

Tags: mysql, database

i was trying to enable slow_query_log. i have downloaded my.cnf file from server using WinSCP and added the code for enabling slow_query_log.

```
slow_query_log = ON
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql_slow.log
```

And when i restart my server i am getting this error `mysql has failed, please contact the sysadmin (result was "mysql is not running").`
here i am adding my my.cnf file
 i have tried with `slow_query_log = 1` also. But getting the same error. when i remove the code which i have added the error is gone. Any one please help me...

**my.cnf**

```
    [mysqld]
datadir=/home/mysql/
tmpdir=/home/mysqltmp
#max_connections = 175 #was 175
max_connections = 80
#max_connect_errors = 350 #was 250
max_connect_errors = 250
safe-show-database
skip-locking
key_buffer = 1024M # was 128M
max_allowed_packet = 6M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M

#old settings, for 900 ish max maxconn
#sort_buffer_size = 32M
#read_buffer_size = 32M
#read_rnd_buffer_size = 32M

sort_buffer_size = 5M
read_buffer_size = 5M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 5M

query_cache_size= 1024M
query_cache_limit= 16M
max_heap_table_size = 128M
tmp_table_size = 128M
thread_concurrency = 16
wait_timeout = 10
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_log_file_size = 10485760
open_files_limit = 8192
low_priority_updates = 1 
slow_query_log = ON
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql_slow.log

# who set these? these are NOT memory settings, but rather integer settings.
#table_cache = 1024M
#thread_cache_size = 8M

table_cache = 512
thread_cache_size = 8

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash

[isamchk]
key_buffer = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 128M
sort_buffer_size = 128M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M
```

Comment: Please contact your sysadmin, as your mysql asks you

Comment: @zerkms i want to know is there any error in my code which i have added. if i remove that code its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the file mysql_slow.log in /var/log & change ownerhip of the file:

```
chown mysql.mysql -R /var/log/mysql_slow.log
```

either value (1 or ON) should work for the slow query log.

also, are you using regular statements?

Comment: what should be the the permission for that file? Now the file having permission (rw-r--r--)

Comment: and what should i do with this code `chown mysql.mysql -R /var/log/mysql_slow.log` can you make it more clear

Comment: just execute this command on linux terminal or konsole to change ownership of folder

Comment: sorry for the short response - try the chmod or chown commands to ensure that mysql has write access to the directory where the log file needs to be generated.  I would also suggest that you create the empty log file and check if mysql can write to it.  best of luck and hoping this solves it for you

Answer (score 0):

check for ownership as mysql.mysql and permissions on file `/var/log/mysql_slow.log`

```
ls -al /var/log/mysql_slow.log
```

Comment: what should be the the permission for that file? Now the file having permission `(rw-r--r--)`